# Using case class to import csv in scala

Tags: scala, case-class, azure-databricks, import-csv

Team,
In databricks, currently we are using StructType to create the data schema and load the csv file to a dataframe, doing necessary operations and exporting it into CSV.
We would like to see if there are any other approaches to increase performance. 
Can we create objects and load file using case classes? 
If there is any such process, can some one share link/documentation?

and Which one will be more efficient: Object or Dataframe?

Thanks,
Srini

Comment: You can do something like `spark.read.schema(implicitly[Encoder[CaseClass]].schema).csv(path = "file.csv").as[CaseClass]` - you need to `import spark.implicits._` before.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I'm receiving the following error : <br>
command-693589289394815:1: error: not found: type Encoder
spark.read.schema(implicitly[Encoder[inputclass]].schema)

Comment: You have to import it... `import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder`...

Comment: Thank you @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez . it helped